# How to URL encode a URI route parameter in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, uri, laravel-routing, laravel-7

I have a URI I need to pass inside a route to a controller. How do I handle this, or more specifically, how can I pass a string that would typically need to be URL encoded first? Could this be Howhandledy, a regular expression constraint in the route?

**String to pass**

```
itm:n#_123445
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('getChildren/{uri}', 'ChildrenController@getChildren');
```

Comment: Are you attempting to store this uri, or are you using this uri as a unique identifier to get some other data to return to the user?

Comment: @mchljams I don't need to store it. This (itm:n#_123445) would be sent via AJAX to the Laravel route: getChildren/itm:n#_123445. I guess it might be better to eliminate the underscore and everything before it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `URL` facade to do that.
Full path is `Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL` or just use `\URL` since it is added in `config/app.php` file.

**Usage**:

```
URL::to('/getChildren', ['itm:n#_123445']));
```

**Generated url**:

```
http://domain.test/getChildren/itm%3An%23_123445
```

**Handling**

```
Route::get('getChildren/{url}', function ($url) {
    dd($url); // itm:n#_123445

});
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: What if i want to use the route name?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend updating your table schema to create a unique id for each uri in the DB, if it does not already have one. Instead of passing the full uri as a parameter, you would pass the id instead.

Answer (score 0):

First off,

If you are using this specific format, the browser will understand the `#` as a reference to an anchor in the page - just like this example: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/packages#views

and won't pass the number to the backend - as you mention you most likely will have to encode the URL before sending it

Now if you are sure that the backend can receive this format, I would do a preg_match in a middleware (if this format is recurrent) or directly in the controller to extract the numerical id.

```
preg_match('/itm:n#_(\d*)/', $uri , $matches);
$id = matches[0]
```